# Multiple references to enumerate items of different hierarchy

Tags: enumerate, ref

How do I use `\ref` when I have to link to two items at different hierarchy? See the minimal working example. When I use `\ref{t1}`, I get `(I)`, which is good. When I use `\ref{t1-1}`, I get `(A)`, which is also good. But I want to have `(IA)` (or may be more customised `(I-A)` or `(I/A)`) when I use `ref` both of them together. With naive approach, I can produce `(I)(A)` which is not good.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate, enumitem}

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\Roman*)]
        \item\label{t1} Topping
        \begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*)]
            \item\label{t1-1} Aloe vera
            \item Cream
        \end{enumerate} 
    \end{enumerate}

A Tea \ref{t1}\ref{t1-1} for me! 
% But I wanted (IA)!!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ref option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\Roman*)]
        \item\label{t1} Topping
        \begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),ref=(\Roman{enumi}-\Alph*)]
            \item\label{t1-1} Aloe vera
            \item Cream
        \end{enumerate} 
    \end{enumerate}

A Tea \ref{t1-1} for me! 
% But I wanted (IA)!!
\end{document}
```

Comment: You probably only need `\ref{t1-1}` and it should be `ref=(\Roman{enumi}\Alph*)`.

Comment: @Werner I see. Thank you, but i think there is no problem here.